# Print two numbers side by side in nested loop

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

Ive got a nested loop construct like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7;i++){
for(int j = 0; j < 5 ;j++){
    //do some thing here
  }
}
```

I want result format like as:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4 
5 0
6 1
```

Comment: Is this an assignment? Are you required to only use two loops? Have you tried printing i and j?

Comment: You just need one loop in this case and a variable, which should get reset when actual loop counter divisible by 5.

Comment: This is not a job for a nested loop. Have just one loop, and look into the modulo operator `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 7;i++){
        System.out.println(i + " "+(i%5));
      }
  }
```

OUTPUT :

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 0
6 1
```